# Decoupled process from terminal still outputs Traceback to the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, process, subprocess, traceback

While testing an application I made using a rest api I discovered this behaviour which I don't understand.
Lets start by reproducing a similar error as follows -
In file `call.py` -
**Note** that this file has code that manifests itself visually for example a GUI that runs forever. Here I am just showing you a representation and deliberately making it raise an Exception to show you the issue. Making a get request and then trying to parse the result as json will raise a `JSONDecodeError`.

```
import requests
from time import sleep

sleep(3)
uri = 'https://google.com'
r = requests.get(uri)
response_dict = r.json()
```

Since I want to run this as a daemon process, I decouple this process from the terminal that started it using the following trick -
In file `start.py` -

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.Popen(["python3", "call.py"])
sys.exit(0)
```

And then I execute `python3 start.py`
It **apparently** decouples the process because if there are no exceptions the visual manifestation runs perfectly.
However in case of an exception I immediately see this output in the terminal, even though I got a new prompt after calling `python3 start.py` -

```
$ python3 start.py
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call.py", line 7, in <module>
    response_dict = r.json()
  File "/home/walker/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 896, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Now, I understand that all exceptions MUST be handled in the program itself. And I have done it after this strange issue, but what is not clear to me is **why did this happen at all in the first place**?
It doesn't happen if I quit the terminal and restart the terminal (the visual manifestation gets stuck in case of a Traceback, and no output on any terminal as expected)
Why is a decoupled process behaving this way?
**NOTE**: Decoupling is imperative to me. It is imperative that the GUI run as a background or daemon process and that the terminal that spawns it is freed from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by "decoupled", I assume you mean you want the stdout/stderr to go to `/dev/null`?  assuming that's what you mean, that's not what you've told your code to do

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and `None`.
>
> With the default settings of `None`, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.

you therefore probably want to be doing:

```
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL

Popen(["python3", "call.py"], stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

based on the OPs comment, I think they might be after a tool like GNU `screen` or `tmux`.  terminal multiplexers, like these, allow you to create a virtual terminal that you can disconnect from and reconnect to at need.  these answers see https://askubuntu.com/a/220880/106239 and  https://askubuntu.com/a/8657/106239 have examples for `tmux` and `screen` respectively

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea if this is the correct way to "decouple" ? By "decoupling" i basically mean that the terminal that starts the process must become free of the process (usually until and unless the process finishes, we don't get a new prompt, right?) . Is it possible to do this from WITHIN the same program (not writing `start.py`. And I want this to happen because of the fact that this is a very long running diagnostic program that basically runs as long as my laptop is ON.

Comment: @raj I've updated my answer based on this comment, hope I've interpreted correctly!

Comment: Thanks a lot but I had actually browsed quite a few resources about tools like `nohup` , 'screen` etc. The issue with them is that they are platform specific and (or) require additional installation. My idea was that since Python's libraries have matured and modules like `subprocess`, `threading` etc have come up, it should be possible to do what we are doing using `Popen` but without the the additional script. I am satisfied with `Popen`, its just that I think there is a better solution that that. I really dont want to use additional tools to do what we are doing by `Popen` now.

Comment: the concept of GUIs and background processes are pretty platform specific; have you ever done any embedded development?  I'd stick with the tools for the OS I'm initially targeting and worry about porting if/when that becomes important